# What's does the Pinterest pintrk('page') javascript method do?

Tags: javascript, pinterest

When integrating the Pinterest tracking code into into the javascript of a website what does the `pintrk('page')` call do? At first blush it looked like it probably recorded the page view, but then I noticed that there is a separate JavaScript method call `pintrk('track', 'pagevisit');` used for that.

And alot of sample code blocks show both being used together.  So for example, on this pinterest developers page https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/ad-tools/conversion-tag/? there is the following code block that uses both calls:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  !function(e){if(!window.pintrk){window.pintrk=function(){window.pintrk.queue.push(
    Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))};var
    n=window.pintrk;n.queue=[],n.version="3.0";var
    t=document.createElement("script");t.async=!0,t.src=e;var
    r=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];r.parentNode.insertBefore(t,r)}}
    ("https://s.pinimg.com/ct/core.js"); 
    pintrk('load', '123456789'); 
    pintrk('page'); //<---HERE
  </script>
  <noscript>
    <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none;" alt="" src="https://ct.pinterest.com/v3/?tid=123456789&noscript=1" />
  </noscript>
  <script>
    pintrk('track', 'pagevisit');    //<----HERE
  </script>
  <noscript>
    <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none;" alt="" src="https://ct.pinterest.com/v3/?tid=123456789&event=pagevisit&noscript=1" />
  </noscript>
</head>
```

The page this code comes from states that the `pintrk('track', 'pagevisit');` records a pagevisit.  Seems intuitive enough. ;-)

But what is the purpose of `pintrk('page');` from a Pinterest analytics perspective?

Comment: All it does is push the value `['page']` to the `pintrk.queue` array. Then, the `https://s.pinimg.com/ct/core.js` script will probably read that array (and maybe even overwrite the `pintrk` function), but you will need to study that code to see what it does with the queued value. Or read the usage documentation, if that exists.

Comment: (grin) Great comment.  Love it.  I'm hoping to understand what the call does from an analytics perspective.  I will update by question to indicate that.  I have studied the usage documentation and it's undocumented as far as I can tell, other than appearing in code samples.

Comment: Oh, sorry for the misunderstanding. Maybe ask for "What is the purpose of this call in that snippet?", not for "What does it do?" (aka "How does it work?").

Comment: @Bergi  I loved your comment.  It was on point.  (Hence my upvote) The miscommunication was all mine.  It made me realized I should have been a bit more specific. I reworked the last sentence to clarify using your feedback.